# Relation between range of $\sin(\pi x)$ and $\sin(b^n \pi x)$ on a monotonic region when $|b| > 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, trigonometry

If $|b| > 1$ then $\sin(b^n \pi x)$ compresses the $\sin(\pi x)$ graph horizontally by a factor of $b^n$:

[image]

The idea that comes to mind is that:

> If $x_0 \in [x_1,x_2]$ and $\sin(\pi x)$ is monotonic in that region without changing the sign and $|b| > 1$ and $x \neq \frac{p}{b^q} $ when $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$, then for infinity $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$, also $\sin(b^n \pi x_0)$ is between $\sin(x_1)$ and $\sin(x_2)$.

Is above guess true? I want to find prove or disprove for that. I think it must be provable by [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property); but do not know how.

Comment: Do you know what happens to the graph of $f(x)$ compared to the graph of $f(\alpha x)$ depending on whether $0<\alpha<1$ or $\alpha\ge 1$ ? Draw some graphs for $b=\sqrt[n]{\frac{m}\pi}>1.$

Comment: This isn't true, if $b = 2, x_0 = 1/4, x_1 = 1/4 - .001, x_2 = 1/4+.001$, you'll see that for all but finitely many $n$, $\sin(b^n \pi x_0) = \sin(2^{n-2}\pi) = 0 \not\in [\sin(x_1),\sin(x_2)].$

Answer (score 1):

For this specific question the answer is no (if we cherry pick the $x_0$ and $b$ we are starting with.)

Let $b = 2, x_0 = 1/4, x_1 = 1/4 - .001, x_2 = 1/4 + .001.$ Note that
$$\sin(b^2\pi x_0) = \sin(2^{n-2}\pi) = 0 \not\in [\sin(x_1),\sin(x_2)]$$
for $n \geq 3$.

In response to the OPs edit, use the binary expansion of $x = .b_1b_2b_3...$ where $b_n \in \{0,1\}$. Pick $b = 2$, so the binary expansion of $2^n x$ is just the binary expansion of $x$ shifted $n$ places to the left. Note that any irrational number has a binary expansion that does not terminate and does not repeat. To generate a counter example (or to generate one that suits the OP's hypothesis,) we need to pick an interval sufficiently small.

For example, we pick the interval $[x_1,x_2] = [\pi 2^{-10}, \pi 2^{-9}].$ If we pick $x$ an irrational number in this interval such that the binary expansion of $x$ only contains finitely many instances of 9 consecutive zeros, $2^n \pi x$ will never be inside $[x_1,x_2]$ aside from finitely many $n$ and so we have found a negative counterexample.

For irrational numbers whose binary expansions contain every finite digit string infinitely many times, the result will hold.

Comment: +1 vote; But I edited my question. What about $x \neq \frac{p}{b^q} \text{when } p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$?